# Determine sql server installation (server or client tools only)

Tags: sql-server, installation

Think about the situation that you have a software audit.
The company use a software facility management tool to determine installed software on a machine.
This software that seek for installed software is able to create packages to find software.

At the moment the software seeks for special registry keys to see if sql server is installed.

I got a false alert on one machine, because there only management studio (client tools) are installed.
So I need to identify if the full server database server is installed or client tools only. Can I determine this finding registry keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look here :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLServer 
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server

**SQL Server 2008 R2**

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersionSQL

**SQL Server 2008**

- SQL Server Native Client 10 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion

**SQL Server 2005**

- SQL Server Native Client 9 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Native Client\CurrentVersion

Comment: I knew the software keys, already checking them, but this don't tell me if there is just client tools installed or a server running. But checking the existance of a sql server service will do it, good idea.